# How to / Should one - set EntityState in UI/BL Layer?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-access-layer, bll

I have a segregation of layers as follows:

> UI       - Web App                         => References BLL And
>   Entities
>
> BLL      - Business Logic (Validations)    => References DAL And
>   Entities
>
> Entities - Data Carries (POCO)             => No Reference
>
> DAL      - Data Context EDMX               => No Reference

I have a very basic question, since this is my first project with absolute segregation.
If I want to set EntityState (Added/Modified/Deleted) of my objects @ UI level, how do I do that. Because with the above structure I won't have access to the **DataContext**.

Because for all I know to set the Entity State, data context is a mandate.

I have read a lot questions on SO, but none had a clarification of this doubt. I know one other way would be maintaining a custom State property @ Entities level.

I have read that datacontext should be limited to DAL. Is it a bad practice to set EntityState it @BLL/UI?

I'm new to EF with this kind of architecture.Please help.

I have gone through the following So questions but did not get clarity, may be it is due to my lack of knowledge of SOC:

1.[Which layer should create DataContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490863/which-layer-should-create-datacontext)

2.[Why DbContext object shouldn't be referred in Service Layer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244446/why-dbcontext-object-shouldnt-be-referred-in-service-layer)

3.[If Entity Framework / DbContext is the DAL / Repository, where does it fit within 3-tier architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869380/if-entity-framework-dbcontext-is-the-dal-repository-where-does-it-fit-withi)

4.[Entity Framework and layer separation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126285/entity-framework-and-layer-separation?rq=1)

4.[How to update entities which are modified outside the DbContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296751/how-to-update-entities-which-are-modified-outside-the-dbcontext)

**EDIT 1:**
One thing I'm still concerned about is looping through the object hierarchy again in DAL just to set their EntityState.I have a pretty much nested hierarchy. If I had to do the same in a flat structure I would have to set it once in the UI where objects are filled and can then call context.savechanges().

But here I have made a dummy state property for entity, which I can set @UI and later translate that to EntityState.Modified @DAL. Is this a right approach?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need to set the entity state in the UI? what do you mean by that?

Comment: @SOfanatic Lets say i have a grid which represents an entity and i modify the second rows data.I have to mark it as dirty(modified) for my context to know that this entity has to be updated..right? I could be wrong as my experience with EF is very limited

Comment: I guess that would be one way to handle it... but not sure if it's the best way. Just to be clear, your grid is a collection of entities not just 1 single entity right?

Comment: @SOfanatic - yes a collection entities.I have forms which have data of multiple entities with a nested hierarchy(1 to many) .. so i have to update/add/delete the entire hierarchy based on data user has selected.What are the other ways of handling it, any links refrences would be of great help

Comment: I don't have any links but a better approach would be to do ajax calls? possibly using a client MVVM framework (like knockout.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your `DAL` should have access to your `DataContext` (indirectly). The `DataContext` should be created/retrieved by a `ContextFactory` that is inserted into your `BaseRepository`. Somewhere in your factory class you should have a method that retrieves the `DataContext`:

```
public DataContext Get()
{
    return _dataContext ?? (dataContext = new DataContext());
}
```

Let's say in your repository you have an `Update(T entity)` method, then that's where you handle the state:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: This helped me solve another issue of multiple instances of data context. Please check edit 1 of my question.